# Rename SAS columns using pattern matching

Tags: regex, sas

Working in SAS here, and have a lot of column names that I'd like to drop a pattern from. This is pretty straightforward in R:

```
colnames(data) <- gsub('drop_pattern', '', colnames(data))
```

But is there an equivalently elegant SAS way?

Comment: Is sas regex capable ?

Comment: Possible? Yes. Elegant? No...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the RENAME statement in PROC DATASETS to modify the names of variables in a dataset without having to make a new dataset.

```
proc datasets lib=mylib nolist;
  modify mydata ;
    rename freddrop_patterndy = freddy samdrop_patternmy=sammy ;
  run;
quit;
```

You can use any number of functions, including those that support regular expressions, to construct a new name from an old name. For example if you just want to remove some constant text then something like this could work:

```
new_name = transtrn(old_name,'drop_pattern',trimn(' '));
```

You can use a query against the metadata of the variable names to generate the oldname=newname pairs into a macro variable.

```
proc sql noprint ;
  select catx('=',name,transtrn(old_name,'drop_pattern',trimn(' '))
    into :rename_list separated by ' '
  from dictionary.column
  where libname='MYLIB' and memname='MYDATA' and index(name,'drop_pattern')
  ;
quit;
```

Then you can use the macro variable in your code.  You will probably need to skip this step if there are no names that need to be changed.

```
%if &sqlobs %then %do ;
proc datasets lib=mylib nolist;
  modify mydata ;
    rename &rename_list ;
  run;
quit;
%end;
```

Note if you have set the VALIDVARNAME option to ANY then you will need to use the NLITERAL() function when generating the oldname=newname pairs to handle names that might not follow normal naming rules.

```
select catx('=',nliteral(name),nliteral(transtrn(old_name,'drop_pattern',trimn(' ')))
```